# Simple font not changing

Tags: html, css, fonts

```
<p style=" font-family: 'Grinched 2.0'; 
    font-size:50px; 
    margin-left:150px; 
    top:1500px; 
    position: absolute;">Apply now for a position in our team, send us</p>
```

Its very silly problem but seriously its 3hrs now and I cant solve it!

This is simple html code where I set my font! When I access it from computer it works well! But when I access the site through mobile, the font family attribute is not applied! Rest of all the stuffs like the positions is working fine! What is the fault?

Comment: well, does your mobile have that font installed? saying it works on your desktop is rather useless. "well, gee, speaking german worked when I was in germany. why doesn't it work in china?"

Comment: you can host the font on your server or using CDN for example, like @MarcB said, you need to "teach" your "China" to speak "German".

Comment: I have made 2 versions of the site! One is mobile and other is desktop compatible. Even if as you say font is not installed in mobile, but i can see the font on the site when I accessed the desktop version site through  mobile! so i can say that wont be the issue about font installation.

Comment: Maybe a link to your site could help.

Comment: Desktop: http://tgg.esy.es/
Mobile: http://m.tgg.esy.es/

Comment: @JayantKudav: so what? If the font is installed on your desktop system, it'll work on the site, because your web browser can/will use system fonts. but if that same font is **NOT** installed on your mobile, and you don't include the appropriate css directives to tell the mobile where to GET the font, then it can't do anything to display it.

Comment: Yaa I understood your point! But I am able to see the font on my mobile if i access  tgg.esy.es. But I cant see the font if I access it from here :  m.tgg.esy.es. And the code is the same! dont know whats going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Marc B suggested, if you don't have the font installed on your mobile then it won't display.

To integrate non-default font on the web, you need to use the `@font-face` rule. Once you have registered your font with @font-face, you can use it in your css. However, it is recommended to always keep some default font as a fallback for browsers that don't support `@font-face`or if anything happen with your font.

Here is an exemple from [Mozilla Developper Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face)

```
@font-face { // This will register your font
  font-family: "Bitstream Vera Serif Bold";
  src: url("http://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/2934/=VeraSeBd.ttf");
}

p { //Then you can use it like so
    font-family: "Bitstream Vera Serif Bold", serif;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Now that we can see your website, I am sure that the issue is coming from the fact that you don't register the `Grinched 2.0` font. This explains why when viewed from your desktop (which has the font installed) either site will show the font but not on mobile.

If you follow my example above it will work. This little tool can help you get your font ready and will give you the code you need: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: Well I did this: @font-face { 
  font-family: "Grinched 2.0";
  src: url(" http://tgg.esy.es/Grinched 2.0.ttf");
}

Comment: Rename your file grinched20.ttf (no space) and then modify your url with the new file name: `url(tag.esy.es/grinched20.ttf)`. You will also need `woff`, `woffs` and `svg` format if you want it to work on all devices and browsers.

Comment: Well I used that tool...generated files... uploaded them! I copied the stylesheet to my style.css file! Still didnt get the font! anything wrong I did?

Comment: The first line of the `@font-face` rule gives you the name to use under the `font-family` property. In your case, you should use: `grinched_2.0regular` instead of `Grinched 2.0`.

Comment: Thanks your normal solution worked! ;) God bless you! ;)

Answer (score 0):

This font is available in your site and set it up in css?
For ex.:

`myfont.css` file

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Grinched 2.0';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url(/fonts/Grinched 2.0.eot); /* For IE6-8 */
    url(/fonts/Grinched 2.0.woff) format('woff'),
    url(/fonts/Grinched 2.0.woff2) format('woff2'),
    url(/fonts/Grinched 2.0.ttf) format('truetype'),
    url(/fonts/Grinched 2.0.svg) format('svg');
}
```

and use this in your html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/font-material.css">
```

and css:

```
p {
    font-family: 'Grinched 2.0';
}
```

Comment: ohkk i need to try it!